# Unholy Grail Layout (Reverse Holy Grail Layout)

Tags: code-golf, css

The Holy Grail Layout in CSS, is a full height, 3 column layout which consists of a fluid central column, and two side columns with fixed widths.

### Your Task is Simple!

Reverse it, make a fixed width central column, and two fluid width columns to the sides. The point is for them to take **All available space *both vertically and horizontally***. So if one adds elements above, or elements below (assume 100% width), your solution should shrink to accommodate. Same goes with elements on the sides. Your layout should fill 100% of its container's space.

### Restrictions

- HTML and CSS only (no JavaScript)
- IE8+ support mandatory
- Must work in all major browsers (it is, after all, a layout!)
- HTML and CSS must both be **valid**.
- No tables, it's supposed to be a layout, not an abomination.

### Winner

- Code with fewest characters wins, **excess spaces and newlines do not count, don't be afraid to be readable!** (I'm running the solution through a minifier)

---

Good luck!

Comment: The specification is a bit vague, but on the assumption that it can be tightened up, how would you pick a winner between two solutions? [All questions on this site should have an objective primary winning criterion](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Well, with the lack of a better criterion, I'd say it would be shortest code possible. I'll edit it as soon as I get to a PC.

Comment: How about providing a list of browsers to support, then score by the following?  [code size] / [number of actually supported browsers]

Comment: I think the current attempt at an answer validates my comment that the specification is a bit vague. Can you give a precise definition of what counts as a "column"?

Comment: @PeterTaylor As always: Proof by example. I don't know yet if this is counter productive or not.

Comment: I will update the criteria when I get to a PC later today.

Comment: Edited to make clear (tell me if you still need more information). Sorry for those whose solutions were invalidated. (My first puzzle on this site :D)

Answer (score 2):

Simple

```
<div style=float:left;>L</div><div style=float:right;>R</div><div style="width: 100px;margin:0px auto;">C</div>
```

- Who said that it needs to be valid html?
- Who said that I need a doctype?

Answer (score 1):

display:table-cell is compatible ie8+ (as seen in caniuse)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>a</title>
  <style>
    html { height: 100%}
    body { margin: 0; display: table; height: 100%; width: 100%}
    .c { display: table-cell }
    .c2 { width: 6em }
  </style>
</head>

<a class="c c1">a</a>
<a class="c c2">z</a>
<a class="c c3">e</a>
```

This is html/css valid, tried here : https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea

That's why there is head/title stuff.
But you can ommit html/body, according to the specs.

The issue I see is when you want to put something above/below, you have to make them `display: table-row`, and probably specify a `height`.

Comment: Why the downvotes ? Based on (not so clear) requirements, this answer is quite acceptable

Answer (score 0):

Guaranteed to work in all browsers - old and new:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td class="f">b</td>
    <td>c</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table, tr{
    width: 100%;
}
.f{
    width:100px;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8QWBX/1/

Note: if you want to make it shorter (but fail HTML standards) you may remove the `tr` tag and its styling. This will save 12 characters the way I see it.

Comment: Table for layout? I feel ill.